# System booted up, but can't login as root

Tags: login, root

I just got my system to boot up (Scientific Linux), but at the login screen I can't login as root. It doesn't even ask for a password, just says `Login incorrect`.

So what I see is:

```
localhost login: root
login incorrect
```

Then:

```
login: root
Login incorrect
```

What did I break this time? I was messing around with essential filesystem files a lot, namely `/bin` and `/sbin`.

Comment: This could have several causes which are all due to abnormal changes, possibly related to what you did.  You should boot from a USB drive (or key) and check the system logs which I assume will probably give more information on the issue.

Comment: Hmm. How would I do this if I am using a custom root fs image for a network boot?

Comment: Alright, if I boot at runlevel 1 (single-user mode) I have access to my filesystem as root. Where would the logs be located? Looking at another forum post, I think `init 3 ; sleep 10 ; tail /var/log/messages > ~/log` may help me, but I don't really understand it. Doing that at runlevel 1 brought me back to the login screen, but also kept me as root, so there was some weird glitching.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Turns out a few libraries necessary for the `login` binary were missing, namely `libcrack.so.2.8.0` and a version of `libglib`. These were supposed to be located in `/usr/lib`, and my image's `/usr/lib` directory was empty. I copied the necessary files in from the `/usr/lib` directory of a different, working OS (same type and version).

So, after doing:

```
cp -ap libcrack* /my/image/directory/mount/usr/lib
cp -ap libglib* /my/image/directory/mount/usr/lib
```

I am able to log in.